# Rails cache do inside module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, module

Hot can I use cache do command inside module?

Example

```
module MyModule
  def self.some_method(str)
    cache str do
      ... some code ...
    end
  end
end
```

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Rails, you can do it like so:

```
module MyModule
  def self.some_method(str)
    Rails.cache.fetch(str) do
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```